# Running an executable in virtual machine through base machine

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware-workstation, remote

I want to launch an executable in my virtual machine(Windows Server 2003 OS and is installed using VMWARE Workstation) from my base machine

I tried the following command

```
"C:\Program Files\VMware\VMware VIX\vmrun" -T server -h https://machine-name.domain-name:8333/sdk -u username -p password -gu guestusername -gp guestpassword runProgramInGuest "[standard] vmname/vmname.vmx" -activeWindow "C:\windows\system32\notepad.exe"
```

On doing this notepad doesn't shows up but on opening taskmanager it shows notepad.exe running  under my account

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked by adding the keyword -interactive .....

Without it the GUI won't come..

Hence the command which works fine is

"C:\Program Files\VMware\VMware VIX\vmrun" -T server -h https://machine-name.domain-name:8333/sdk -u username -p password -gu guestusername -gp guestpassword runProgramInGuest "[standard] vmname/vmname.vmx" -activeWindow -interactive "C:\windows\system32\notepad.exe"